# SQL SERVER. Sumar el importe de todos los registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema de ejemplo sobre transacciones de un banco. 
Mi tabla contiene muchos datos como Caja, Oficina, Nombre, Apellidos, Fecha, DNI, Importe, Tipo...

Cada caja (que hay varias) tiene varias oficinas, y éstas a su vez tienen muchos clientes.
Tras unas cuantas consultas anteriores he llegado a la siguiente, por lo que tengo que partir sí o sí de ella:

```
      SELECT Caja, Oficina, MIN(NombreCompleto) AS Persona
      FROM (
            SELECT Caja, Oficina, DNI, MIN(Nombre+Apellidos) AS NombreCompleto, Importe
            FROM miTabla
            WHERE Importe > 50
            GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, DNI, Importe) as tabla1
      GROUP BY Caja, Oficina
      ORDER BY Caja, Oficina, Nombre
```

Esto me muestra la primera persona por orden alfabético (ej. Alberto Álvarez) dentro de todas las oficinas, dentro a su vez de cada caja. Es decir, una persona por oficina.

Entonces ahora lo que necesito es que aparezca también un 4º campo (aparte de caja, oficina, persona, que ya me muestra la consulta anterior) que sea la suma de todos los importes asociados a dichas personas que ya me aparecen.

Es decir, si me aparecen 5 personas, quiero sumar el importe que tiene cada una de ellas y que el resultado me aparezca y se repita a lo largo de toda la salida.

Estoy probando metiendo el    SUM(Importe) en varios lados pero no me sale. Espero que se me entienda.

Gracias.

Comment: saca importe del group by, y reemplaza importe en el select por sum(importe). Con eso deberia funcionar. pero ojo que va a sumar por caja oficina y dni..ahora que miro bien, pero no haces nada con el importe!.. y que sentido tiene el segundo group by, si deberia devolver lo mismo que el primero, menos el importe que no lo usas en el segundo. Hace las cosas en orden, me parece que hay cosas de mas...

Comment: dni no esta asociado con una persona siempre?? no te esta mostrando todas las personas???

Comment: Vale, un momento, que me he confundido de consulta, lo que ya tengo puesto arriba es tontería, ahora pongo desde donde parto

Comment: que es dni? seguro te muesta lo que queres? si dni es 1 a 1 con nombre (como sospecho) entonces estas trayendo todos los registros, no le esta haciendo caso al group by...

Answer (score 3):

Listo, mejor explicada tu pregunta el query de aqui abajo te sirve:

```
SELECT S3.Caja, s3.Oficina, S3.DNI, S3.Persona, SUM(S3.Importe)
FROM(
    SELECT S1.Caja, S1.Oficina, S1.DNI, S1.Persona, S2.Importe
    FROM(
        SELECT Caja, Oficina, DNI, MIN(IsNUll(Nombre, '') + ' ' + IsNull(Apellido, '')) As Persona
        FROM miTabla AS A
        WHERE IMPORTE > 50
        GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, DNI) AS S1,
        (SELECT Caja, Oficina, DNI, MIN(IsNUll(Nombre, '') + ' ' + IsNull(Apellido, ''), Importe) As Persona
        FROM miTabla AS A
        WHERE IMPORTE > 50) AS S2
    WHERE S1.Persona = S2.Persona) AS S3
GROUP BY S3.Caja, s3.Oficina, S3.DNI, S3.Persona
```

En el cual:

- S1, es el select las primeras personas ordenadas alfabéticamente.
- S2, es la tabla misma con todas las personas y sus importes
- S3, es la consulta que te vincula a las personas del conjunto S1 y S2 por su nombre, y con ello obtienes lo que deseas mediante un agrupamiento.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Ojo que en S2 no esta el importe, hiciste mal el copy paste del select.

Comment: Muchas gracias por esa importante acotación @gbianchi!. Saludos.

Comment: ahora.. si de S2 solo necesitas persona e importe, que sentido tienen todos los otros campos en el select? esto ya es de purista, porque si le vamos a enseñar (ya hizo varias preguntas sobre el mismo tema OP), por lo menos que quede mas lindo ;) igual la respuesta esta bien.

Comment: Pues que le podemos hacer?? (: ! Gracias por la mano, saludos y exitos!

Comment: De donde se toma el s2.importe, al tomar la sub consulta necesita devolverlo también el S1 o no?

Comment: @angelsolano generé 2 conjuntos de resultados como explico en la respuesta, el uno solo son las personas con las cuales partir, y el segundo son todos los datos. Por ello [Importe] solo aparece en S2, para que luego en S3 se haya un match por los nombres y luego agrupar. Saludos.

Comment: pero ahora que vuelvo a mirar.. si una de las consutlas devuelve una sola fila.. y la otra montones.. no van a quedar montones de filas? cual es el sentido de agrupar S1 si va a quedar el mismo resultado al unirlo a la otra tabla? salvo por el importe, tiene el mismo problema que comento en la consulta de OP

Comment: Tienes razón, en todo caso, la repsuesta de abajo es la correcta ya que itera el result set.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo realizaría de esta manera.

```
  ;WITH persona AS
    (
        SELECT Caja, Oficina, DNI, MIN(Nombre+Apellidos) AS NombreCompleto
        FROM miTabla
        WHERE Importe > 50
        GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, DNI
    )

    SELECT  persona.Caja, persona.Oficina, persona.DNI, persona.NombreCompleto, SUM(Importe)
    FROM persona
    JOIN miTabla ON
        miTabla.Caja    = persona.Caja    AND
        miTabla.Oficina = persona.Oficina AND
        miTabla.DNI     = persona.DNI
    GROUP BY persona.Caja, persona.Oficina, persona.DNI, persona.NombreCompleto
```